# Handle multipart/form-data request with a file in Spring Web 4

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, http-post, multipartform-data, spring-4

I am creating a rest controller that looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/clients", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<RestResponse> createClientRecord(
                                                       @RequestPart(value = "imageFile") MultipartFile imageFile,
                                                       @RequestPart(value = "field1") String field1,
                                                       @RequestPart(value = "field2") String field2) {... }
```

I am trying to send a request from Postman by setting body type to be "form-data" in the Postman UI:

[image]

But I am having this error:

```
Status 500 accessing url: '/api/v1/clients' -> UT000072: Failed to decode url ... ... (some unreadable characters) to charset UTF-8
```

My question is: what should I do to handle the http post request with multipart form data with a file in Spring web 4?

Comment: Solved it by changing the annotation from RequestPart to RequestParam and taking out the 'comsumes' value in the POST request annotation. Also re-created DB table, not sure that's relevant ...

Answer (score 0):

Use **org.​springframework.​web.​bind.​annotation.@RequestParam** instead.